# Each value is displayed in a new row HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently working on a small website where my colleagues can see their work times.

- My "rooster" table looks like this:
- rooster_id int(2) Auto_increment primary key.
- personeel_id int(2) //personeel means staff in the Dutch language
  (I'm using inner join to get the person's name).
- dag varchar(10) //dag means day.
- start varchar(5) //start is the time when the employee has to start
  working.
- eind varchar(5) //eind means end.
- datum date
- weeknummer int(2) //weeknummer means weeknumber.

Display:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|rooster_id|personeel_id|dag      |start|eind |datum     |weeknummer|
|1         |1           |Tuesday  |12:00|21:00|2016-05-10|19        |
|1         |1           |Wednesday|15:00|21:00|2016-05-11|19        |
|1         |2           |Monday   |08:00|18:30|2016-05-10|19        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My php code above HTML tag:

```
include_once 'config.php';

$people = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM personeel INNER JOIN rooster ON rooster.personeel_id = personeel.id";
$result = mysql_query($people);
```

My php code inside the table tag:

```
<table cellpadding="1" width="100%" cellspacing="1" class="box-inhoud">
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$row['naam']."</td>";
                            if($row['dag'] === "maandag"){
                                echo "<td class='td-midden'>".$row['start']." - ".$row['eind']."</td>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<td class='td-midden'>Vrij</td>";
                            }
                            if($row['dag'] === "dinsdag"){
                                echo "<td class='td-midden'>".$row['start']." - ".$row['eind']."</td>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<td class='td-midden'>Vrij</td>";
                            }
                            if($row['dag'] === "woensdag"){
                                echo "<td class='td-midden'>".$row['start']." - ".$row['eind']."</td>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<td class='td-midden'>Vrij</td>";
                            }
                            if($row['dag'] === "donderdag"){
                                echo "<td class='td-midden'>".$row['start']." - ".$row['eind']."</td>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<td class='td-midden'>Vrij</td>";
                            }
                            if($row['dag'] === "vrijdag"){
                                echo "<td class='td-midden'>".$row['start']." - ".$row['eind']."</td>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<td class='td-midden'>Vrij</td>";
                            }
                            if($row['dag'] === "zaterdag"){
                                echo "<td class='td-midden'>".$row['start']." - ".$row['eind']."</td>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<td class='td-midden'>Vrij</td>";
                            }
                            if($row['dag'] === "zondag"){
                                if($row['start'] === "00:00:00"){
                                    echo "<td class='td-midden'>Feestdag</td>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "<td class='td-midden'>".$row['start']." - ".$row['eind']."</td>";
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo "<td class='td-midden'>Vrij</td>";
                            }
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
?>
</table>
```

This displays the data like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------
|Employee's|Monday       |Tuesday      |Wednesday    |
|Tom       |Vrij         |12:00 - 21:00|Vrij         |
|Tom       |Vrij         |Vrij         |15:00 - 21:00|
|Jack      |08:00 - 18:30|Vrij         |Vrij         |
------------------------------------------------------
```

It also displays Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday but I didn't want to write all of the days here on stackoverflow since those will have "vrij" as value.

But the thing is, I want to have it like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------
|Employee's|Monday       |Tuesday      |Wednesday    |
|Tom       |Vrij         |12:00 - 21:00|15:00 - 21:00|
|Jack      |08:00 - 18:30|Vrij         |Vrij         |
------------------------------------------------------
```

So every employee does only have 1 row with all their times listed in it.

I'm new on this website so I hope I explained everything good, so you guys can easily help me.

And yes I know, I'm using MySQL because I want to keep it simple and I have never worked with MySQLi nor PDO.

Comment: you need to walk trough db resultset in order to create two deminsional array like `$arr[personeel_id][dag] = 'start - end'` and then to build your table by looping this array.

Comment: I have no idea how to create that, could you please show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go entire example:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test') or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM personeel INNER JOIN rooster ON rooster.personeel_id = personeel.id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $arr = array();
        $nam = array();
        $day = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $nam[$row['id']] = $row['naam'];
            $arr[$row['id']][$row['dag']] = $row['start'] . ' - ' . $row['eind'];
        }
        echo '<table border="1">';
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>Employees</td>';
                foreach($day as $d){
                    echo '<td>'.$d.'</td>';
                }
            echo '</tr>';
            foreach ($nam as $k=>$n){
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$n.'</td>';
                    foreach ($day as $d){
                        if(isset($arr[$k][$d])){
                            echo '<td>'.$arr[$k][$d].'</td>';
                        }else{
                            echo '<td>Virj</td>';
                        }
                    }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        echo '</table>';
    }
?>
```

Output is:

[image]

Some details:

`$nam` array stores all fetched names from personeel together with his id relation.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Tom
    [2] => Jack
)
```

`$arr` is main array which contains relation between personeel id and his data:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Tuesday] => 12:00 - 21:00
            [Wednesday] => 15:00 - 21:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => 08:00 - 18:30
        )

)
```

`$day` is static array with week days.

Walking trough both `$nam` and `$arr` arrays gives you desired table without any duplicates. In addition provided solution uses `mysqli_*` functions, so you can see how to use them.

Hope this will help you to solve your problem. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the solution to my problem and it's also created with MySQLi :)