# Mysql join returns results in multiple rows instead of one for every instance

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

I have three tables: **tbl_days**, **tbl_slots** and **tbl_bookings** as follows.

[image: tbl_days - Contains days in a whole year]

[image: tbl_slots - Contains hourly timings in a day]

[image: tbl_bookings - Contains customer booking data]

Customers are supposed to book for a slot in a day.

Am using the following query:

```
$slots = $this->common->slots();

    if ($slots != NULL) {
        foreach ($slots as $C):
            $start = $C->start;
                 $stop = $C->stop;
                 $slotspace= $start." to ".$stop;

                 $available='Available';
                 $booked ='Booked';

                $sum_col[] = "  IF(tbl_bookings.slot_id =". $C->id.",'".$booked."','".$available."') AS '" . $slotspace . "'";

        endforeach; }


    $sqlquery = $this->db->query("SELECT tbl_days.date_day,

    " . implode(",", $sum_col) . "

    FROM tbl_days
    LEFT JOIN tbl_bookings ON tbl_bookings.date = tbl_days.date_day
    LEFT JOIN tbl_slots ON tbl_slots.id = tbl_bookings.slot_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_fields ON tbl_fields.id = tbl_bookings.field_id 
       ");
    return $sqlquery->result();
```

However, the results display as:[image]

Intended result should be:

[image]

Please note how booking information displays on multiple rows for the same date.

1. Dates to be from the date today (for the next 7 days from today)
2. Display slots for the day on one row.
3. Display the date regardless of if there is a booking or not, like in date 29th.

Kindly help me on how to go about this.
Please note that am using datatables.

Answer (score 0):

So each entry gets displayed in a new row instead of everything that's connected to each other in 1 row, right? I had the same problem in the past and the solution is a second `foreach`. The second one should look at all the records and see if one is connected to another.

See my question: [Each value is displayed in a new row HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048417/each-value-is-displayed-in-a-new-row-html-table)

Comment: Have had a look at it, unfortunately, it hasn't solved my issue.